# Consistency of action perturbation and equation of motion perturbation

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, perturbation-theory

Consider a solution of the equation of motion (EOM) and a perturbation around it, are these two methods equivalent?

1. we first expand our action up to the second order (up to some boundary terms, the first order is zero, because we expand around a solution of the EOM) and then extremize the action with respect to the perturbation.
2. we expand the EOM to the first order.

My guess is that, these are not equivalent. I am specifically interested in GR examples.

For example, suppose we have the following metric:

$$
ds^2=-(1-\frac{2m}{r})(dt^2)+\frac{1}{(1-\frac{2m}{r})}dr^2+r^2(d\Omega^2)
$$
$$
ds_{pert}^2=f(r)(dt^2+2drdt)
$$
Einstein equations are several equations, and it is not always possible to find a nontrivial solution for $f(r)$ among those equations, but from the action point of view, this is just a second order action for $f(r)$ and we always have a solution.

But it is not clear to me why should it be so.

---

EDIT

The Hilbert-Einstein action with cosmological constant is as follow :
$$
S=\int \sqrt{-g}(R-2\Lambda)
$$
where I set $16\pi G_N=1$.

For $AdS_{p+2}$, we have $\Lambda=-\frac{p(p+1)}{2L^2}$.

My real background metric is as follow :

$$
ds^2=\frac{1}{L^2u^2}(-(1-u^3-\zeta^2)dt^2-2\zeta_xdxdt-2\zeta_ydydt +d\vec x^2)+\frac{L^2}{(1-u^3)u^2}du^2
$$
where $\zeta^2=\zeta^2_x+\zeta^2_y$ and $\vec x=(x,y)$. We assume that $\vec\zeta=(\zeta_x,\zeta_y)$ is a constant vector. This a black hole solution in AdS4 and then we consider a perturbation around it as follow :
$$
ds^2_{pert}=\frac{f(u)}{L^2u^2}e^{-i\omega t}dxdy
$$

Now we solve Einstein equation for the perturbation at first order :
$$
G_{\mu\nu}=-\Lambda g_{\mu\nu}$$

for the component {tu}, we have
$$
G_{tu}=i\frac{e^{-i\omega t}\omega\zeta_x\zeta_y f'(u)}{-1+u^3}=0
$$
so f(u) should be a constant function. we may want to compute other component.

but if we perturb the above action up to the second order, we have :

$$
S=\int d^4x\big(-\frac{6}{L^2u^4}-\frac{3(1-u^3)^2-3\zeta^2(1-u^3)+4\zeta_x^2\zeta_y^2}{2L^4u^2(-1+u^3)}~f'^2+\frac{3(-2(-1+u^3)^2+\zeta^2(2-5u^3+3u^6)+(\zeta_x\zeta_y)^2(-2+7u^3))}{L^4u^3(-1+u^3)^2}~ ff'
-\frac{2}{L^4u^2}((-1+u^3)+\zeta^2+\frac{(\zeta_x\zeta_y)^2}{(-1+u^3)})~f.f''
-\frac{1}{2L^4u^4(-1+u^3)^3}((6+7\omega^2L^4u^2-6u^3)(-1+u^3)^2+3\zeta^2(2-4u^3+5u^6)(-1+u^3)+3(\zeta_x\zeta_y)^2(2-6u^3+22u^6))~f^2\Big)
$$
and it's EOM is incompatible with the above Einstein equation for {tu}component.

Comment: Perturbative expansion wrt. what exactly?

Comment: @Qmechanic, consider these two methods, 1)we Plug $g'=g+h$ into the action and then drive the equation of motion for function $f(r)$, 2) we directly solve Einstein equation for our perturbation. but in the first method we just have one equation and in the second method, we have several equations which are Einstein equations which might not be a common factor of each other. Are these two method equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Write
\begin{equation}
g_{\mu\nu}=\bar{g}_{\mu\nu} + h_{\mu\nu}
\end{equation}
where $\bar{g}_{\mu\nu}$ is some *background metric* that satisfies Einstein's equations, with some background stress-energy tensor $\bar{T}_{\mu\nu}$.

Then the following two procedures lead to the same equations of motion for the metric perturbation $h_{\mu\nu}$:

1. Perturb Einstein's equations $G_{\mu\nu}=8\pi G_N T_{\mu\nu}$ to first order in $h_{\mu\nu}$.
2. Perturb the Einstein-Hilbert action $S=\frac{1}{16\pi G_N} \int {\rm d}^4 x \sqrt{-g} \left(R + \mathcal{L}_m\right)$ to second order in $h_{\mu\nu}$, and then set the variation of the action with respect to $h_{\mu\nu}$ to zero.

It's probably easiest to check this explicitly $\bar{g}_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}, \bar{T}_{\mu\nu}=0$ (a flat Minkowski background). Although just as a warning, perturbing the Einstein-Hilbert action to second order in $h_{\mu\nu}$ by hand is a pain. But it works in general.

---

There's nothing mysterious about this. Let's think of a general action $S[\Phi_a]$ for some fields $\Phi_a$.  (I'm being a little fast and loose with the notation but hopefully the idea is clear)

Consider the first procedure. The exact equations of motion are
\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta S}{\delta \Phi_a} =0
\end{equation}
Now write $\Phi_a = \bar{\Phi}_a + \varphi_a$. Then, assuming $\bar{\Phi}_a$ obeys the exact equation, then the equation of motion perturbed to linear order in $\varphi_a$ is
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{\delta^2 S}{\delta \Phi_a \delta \Phi_b}\big|_{\Phi_a=\bar{\Phi_a}} \right) \varphi_b =0
\end{equation}

Now consider the action. Perturbing to quadratic order, the Lagrangian is
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2} \varphi_a \left(\frac{\delta^2 S}{\delta \Phi_a \delta \Phi_b}\Big|_{\Phi=\bar{\Phi}} \right) \varphi_b
\end{equation}
Varying this with respect to $\varphi_a$ yields the same equation we arrived at before
\begin{equation}
\left( \frac{\delta^2 S}{\delta \Phi_a \delta \Phi_b}\big|_{\Phi_a=\bar{\Phi_a}} \right) \varphi_b =0
\end{equation}

Comment: thanks a lot, I am agree with your answer but it didn't resolve my problem. In my question, $\delta g_{tt}=\delta g_{tr}=f(r)$. I summarize my question as follow :  look at my background metric and it's perturbation, if we put that ansatz into the action, after all simplifications, we will have an action for function $f(r)$ which it's EOM is just a single equation, but Einstein equations are 6 equation in d=4 which might be incompatible with each other(for non-trivial solution) and also with the EOM of the action for function $f(r)$. Is my problem clear right now? I have an example like this.

Comment: @Arian I see. Yes, you can do that and you should get the same equation for $f(r)$ either way. An example I am more familiar with is cosmology; if you make an ansatz $ds^2=-N^2(t) dt^2+a^2(t) d\vec{x}^2 $ and put it into the action, you arrive at an action that will give you the Friedmann equations if you vary with respect to $N$ and $a$. The 10 Einstein equations reduce to two in this case; the symmetry of the ansatz means the off-diagonal equations are identically zero, and that the 3-space equations are all equal to each other, so you only have one "time" equation and one "space" equation.

Comment: unfortunately my real background metric is off-diagonal and Einstein equations are satisfied when the perturbation is zero, but the EOM of the action has nontrivial solution. I did my calculations with Mathematica, Do you think that I have a logical error in my calculations?  I edited my question for more detail. I confused about what the problem is.

Comment: @Arian I don't know without looking in more detail, but you should be able to plug an ansatz for the metric into the Einstein-Hilbert action and get the equations of motion for the perturbation functions. One subtlety is related to coordinate freedom; if you fix the coordinate freedom completely in the metric before plugging it into the action, you may only get a subset of the full equations of motion for the perturbations when you vary the action. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for all your comments. I am convinced that this two method should have the same result and I have to find the problem.